# While installing android studio why do i keep getting the error that sdk files not found/downloaded??and how to resolve this?

Tags: android, installation, sdk, android-ide

I keep getting the error in installing android studio regarding sdk files.

I even tried to run it as administrator again but it could not be resolved

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

1st Solution
Download java jdk

JAVA JDK:- https://www.oracle.com/in/java/technologies/downloads/

2nd Solution:- open android studio and click on 3 dot in top side and click SDK Manager and Download all the files. :)